# How to parse an ArcGIS json in google code?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-online, feature-service, google-sheets

I'd like to be able to programmatically query a feature service api and pull the attribute data (I don't really need the geometry for this) into a google sheet. It seems like it ought to be simple but maybe I'm just missing something. I've been playing around with the code at this link here [gist](https://gist.github.com/varun-raj/5350595a730a62ca1954/) and below but so far haven't been able to get it to work, and it seems like it might be out of date.

I'm currently stuck at the code below. When I run the debugger, it looks like while dataAll is populating correctly, the feature variable is not. It looks like 'dataAll[i]' isn't working. Does anyone know why or how to fix it?

> function pullJSON() {   var ss =
>   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 
>   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
>
> ```
> var url="http://your url here"; // Paste your JSON URL here
>  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
>
>    var dataAll = JSON.parse(response); //   Logger.log(dataAll)
> for (i = 0; i<30; i++) {
>   feature = dataAll[i];
>   name = feature.NAME;
>   Logger.log (name)
> }
> ```

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: There is no example to the data, but it looks like it you want to query the properties of the features, My guess (again - based on standard api) is you can get the properties with `let name = feature.properties.NAME`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably help if you posted a sample of the raw GeoJSON that you are receiving, but I would assume that it looks like a typical geoJSON, like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
            [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": { "this": "that" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON#Example)

Your "NAME" attribute should be found in the `properties` object in the `features` list, so you would grab their info like this:

```
for (i = 0; i<30; i++) {
  feature = dataAll.features[i];
  name = feature.properties.NAME;
  Logger.log (name)
}
```

Comment: *For an ESRI response json, "properties" will be "attributes."

Comment: Ah yes, ESRI will be ESRI...

Answer (score 0):

You can do with with OGR2OGR it supports reading WFS or ESRI Feature Service and Read/Write Google Sheet/Fusion Tables.  ogr2ogr -f GFT "GFT:email=john.doe@example.com password=secret_password" URL to service
http://www.gdal.org/drv_gft.html